# Why I can't declare a three dimensional array using a variable in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

So I have this piece of code declaring a three dimensional array:

```
  public class Matrix {   
     private static int n;   
     char[][][] matrix = new char[n][n][2];
     Matrix(int n){
         n=3;
     } }
```

In the constructor of the class,n gets initialized with a value(let's say 3).

The problem is that when I try to access an element of the matrix(let's say matrix[0][0][0]) I get an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

It seems that my matrix has length of 0.

But if I try something like:

```
char[][][] matrix = new char[3][3][2]
```

it works just fine,memory is alocated for the matrix.

Also,in my program I use at some point something like this:

```
char[][] bidimensionalMatrix = new char[n][n];
```

also,works like a charm, I can access the elements of this one too.

Why is this? I am not allowed to specify the dimension of a three dimensional matrix using a variable?

Comment: `n` is `0` when the array is constructed.

Comment: To expand on Oliver's comment. Un-initialized number fields default to `0`

Comment: So you're saying that the memory for my matrix is allocated before the constructor of the class steps in?Because n it's initialized in the constructor of this class.Sorry I didn't post the constructor,I will edit

Comment: Use the `{}` button in the editor for code, not the quote button

Comment: oh,ok,thank you for the advice

Comment: As a side note, it is generally bad to set a `static` variable from your constructor as each time the constructor gets called, it will change the value of the the `static` variable. Either make the variable a member variable, or make the class a singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to define the size of an array with a variable. However, your constructor comes *after* you have initialized the array, and when the array is initialized, 'n' is 0. Remember, array sizes *cannot* be changed once created. Instead, you should initialize the array within your constructor.

```
public class Matrix {   
    private static int n;   
    char[][][] matrix; 

    Matrix(int num){
        n = num;
        matrix = new char[n][n][2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the value of `n` before you can specify the size of the arrays.

Here is a simple class with multiple sized arrays.

```
class Matrix {   
    private int width, height, depth;   
    private char[][][] matrix; 

    public Matrix(int width, int height, int depth) {
        matrix = new char[height][width][depth];
    }

    public void set(int i, int j, int k, char value) {
        matrix[i][j][k] = value;
    }

    public char get(int i, int j, int k) {
        return matrix[i][j][k];
    }
}
```

Sample run

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrix m = new Matrix(2, 2, 2);
    m.set(0, 0, 0, 'c');
    System.out.println(m.get(0, 0, 0)); // c
  }
}
```